# Блокировка файла в bash скрипте

Tags: linux, c, bash

Есть простая программа на C, которая открывает/пишет/закрывает `.bin` файл с использованием `flock()`. Я бы хотел сделать такую же блокировку в bash скрипте, который будет копировать этот `.bin`, чтобы избежать одновременной работы с файлом.

Как я понял из справки (https://linux.die.net/man/1/flock) эту блокировку сделать можно, но будет ли он сотрудничать с "сишным" `flock()`?

Если да, то очень прошу показать простой пример скрипта, где показана работа с flock.

Comment: судя по приведенной справке, она как раз и вызывает сишный flock. Поэтому, если Ваше приложение умеет правильно с flock работать - все будет так как нужно.

Comment: тут приведены примеры http://www.kfirlavi.com/blog/2012/11/06/elegant-locking-of-bash-program/

Answer (score 2):

программа [*flock*](https://linux.die.net/man/1/flock) использует именно системный вызов [*flock()*](https://linux.die.net/man/2/flock). цитата из [исходников](https://anonscm.debian.org/cgit/collab-maint/pkg-util-linux.git/tree/sys-utils/flock.c#n276):

```
        while (flock(fd, type | block)) {
```

описание функции подключено [этой строкой](https://anonscm.debian.org/cgit/collab-maint/pkg-util-linux.git/tree/sys-utils/flock.c#n35):

```
#include <sys/file.h>
```

---

> простой пример скрипта, где показана работа с flock

[например](https://stackoverflow.com/a/169969/4827341):

```
#!/bin/bash

(
  # ожидать блокировки файла /var/lock/.myscript.exclusivelock
  # (файловый дескриптор 200) не более 10 секунд
  flock -x -w 10 200 || exit 1

  # сделать что-нибудь при удачной блокировке

) 200>/var/lock/.myscript.exclusivelock
```

Comment: можно ли так блокировать устройство или лучше создать lock файл рядом?

Comment: @eri, теоретически — можно. но для надёжности лучше создать файл. но не «рядом», а в [специально предназначенном для этого станадартом lsb](http://www.pathname.com/fhs/pub/fhs-2.3.html#VARLOCKLOCKFILES) каталоге `/var/lock` (как приведено в `man flock` и у меня в примере). этот каталог доступен всем для записи. кстати, в стандарте и про «devices» упоминается, так что этот каталог — самое подходящее место и для вашей задачи.