# блокировка последовательного порта на чтение-запись для gcom скрипта

Tags: linux, serial, flock

Есть несколько скриптов для опроса модема по последовательному порту и необходимость запускать их почти в одно время.
gcom не блокирует файл и когда запустится второй скрипт - вывод из порта пойдет на непредсказуемый процесс.

нужно как-то заблокировать устройство на запись и на чтение. Выпадение скрипта допустимо - он потом переподключится.

Есть ли на bash какие варианты поставить файл блокировки? притом что скрипт может упасть.. поэтому необходимо, чтоб эта блокировка разблокировалась при любом исходе.

Comment: блокируйте какой-нибудь «флаговый» файл. https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/612932/178576

Comment: Какое отношение имеет метка embedded к вопросу?!

Comment: embedded обычно применяется для встраиваемых систем, урезанный узерспейс, бизибокс и кастомный линукс.

если у вас другое понимание этого понятия, то лучше удалить этот таг и сделать несколько разных: embedded-linux, embedded-mysql.

Comment: @0andriy, этот таг стоит для привлечения разработчиков embedded linux

Comment: По тексту вопроса и вашему комментарию предлагаю добавить тег C для привлечения внимания разработчиков. И да, я знаю области использования термина embedded.

Comment: специфика разработки на 4х мегабайтах флешки такая, что обычные решения не всегда подходят.

Указание на то где это всё будет применяться я не считаю лишним.