# Запретить одновременное выполнение bash-скрипта

Tags: bash

На Ubuntu-сервере по Crobtab каждую минуту запускается bash-скрипт, который работает некоторое время. 
Необходимо отслеживать в самом скрипте: если предыдущее выполнение скрипта не завершено, то остановить выполнение.
Другими словами, не допустить одновременное выполнение одного и того же bash-скрипта (более одной копии).

Это возможно сделать?

Comment: другой вариант, помимо изложенного @avp — [использовать блокировку файла с помощью программы flock](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/612932/178576)

Comment: @alexandrbarakin, где вы увидели решение у avp?

Answer (score 7):

flock может помочь.

Пример:

```
flock -w0 /tmp/1.lock /1.sh
```

`-w0` не ждать завершения процесса, выходить если он уже запущен

`/tmp/1.lock` - создать lock-файл, указывать в любом удобном месте
**Примечание:** *правильнее использовать каталог* `/var/lock/`

`/1.sh` - путь к скрипту

в кроне запись будет следующим образом:

```
* * * * * user flock -w0 /tmp/1.lock /1.sh
```

Comment: одно замечание: лучше использовать не `/tmp` а [специально предназначенный для этого стандартом lsb каталог `/var/lock`](http://www.pathname.com/fhs/pub/fhs-2.3.html#VARLOCKLOCKFILES).

Answer (score 3):

Да.

Скрипт может проверить, не работает ли его другая копия.

Например, сценарий может быть следующим:

скрипт читает из файла PID и смотрит (команда [kill](https://linux.die.net/man/1/kill)), есть ли процесс с таким PID. Если файла нет или такого PID нет, то он пишет в файл свой PID и работает.

Иначе завершается.

В конце работы скрипт удаляет файл со своим PID.

Comment: Чтение файла неатомарно. Пока вы читате может быть запущена другая копия.

Comment: @0andriy, формально вы правы, но обратите внимание на -- *`" по Crobtab каждую минуту запускается bash-скрипт"`*, что несколько меняет реальные требования к скрипту

Comment: в многопользовательской и многозадачной системе не реального времени нет никакой гарантии, что скрипт, даже самый простой, выполнится за наперёд заданный временной Слот.

Comment: Короче, ваш ответ требует доработки, потому как вашими же словами «кто-то придёт, и решит использовать эту идею», а она  вдруг не сработает.

Comment: @0andriy, пусть это `кто-то` почитает комментарии и другие ответы (добавьте и свой), подумает, поэкспериментирует и сделает как ему хочется. На практике же таких скриптов, как я описал, полно и в основном они успешно работают

Comment: аргумент конечно супер — в мире много программ, написанных с ошибками race conditions, и в основном они работают успешно ;)

Answer (score 2):

А зачем запускать скрипт каждую минуту и при этом смотреть, не отработал ли еще предыдущий скрипт? Просто задача интересна.

Может проще скрипт переделать в сервис и запускать его один раз при старте системы?
И пусть он крутится постоянно. А в сервисе предусмотреть таймаут при отсутствии "работы". А если боитесь, что он упадет и не запустится вновь, то можно вотчдог прикрутить.

Это же логичнее намного, чем в один прекрасный день увидеть сотни висящих в памяти и ожидающих запуска скриптов.