# Как дождаться выполнения cron скрипта?

Tags: centos, cron, sh

Создал cron команду:

```
 */1 * * * *    wget -O /dev/null "https://site.ru/cron.php"
```

Похоже скрипт не успевает отработать за одну минуту, видимо в будущем это приведет к нагрузке на память сервера.

Слышал, что можно создать .sh cron файл, что-то вроде этого:

```
*/1 * * * * /usr/bin/flock -w 60 /var/tmp/myscript.lock /var/www/root/data/www/site.ru/myscript.sh >/dev/null 2>&1
```

Не могу понять, **как правильно создать sh cron задачу** и что необходимо поместить в сам sh файл, чтобы крон выполнялся поочередно, только по завершению выполнения предыдущего **идентичного** задания.

Помогите разобраться, пожалуйста.

Comment: `flock` может работать с командами, для этого нет необходимости создавать скрипт с одной командой `wget`, попробуйте так `* * * * * /usr/bin/flock -w 60 /var/tmp/myscript.lock wget -O /dev/null "https://site.ru/cron.php"` Обратите внимание что `-w 60` - это время освобождения файла дескриптора, т.е. если в течении 60 секунд дескриптор не освободится, то задание отменятся

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Запретить одновременное выполнение bash-скрипта](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/993265/%d0%97%d0%b0%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b5%d1%82%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b2%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b5-%d0%b2%d1%8b%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bb%d0%bd%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-bash-%d1%81%d0%ba%d1%80%d0%b8%d0%bf%d1%82%d0%b0)